# Change the color of patches within a distance Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, patch

I want to change the color of some patches.

```
if mujeres [ ask n-of 20 patches with [pcolor = 35] [set pcolor 9]]
```

However, sometimes two patches adjacent patches change to color 9, i dont want this. I dont think that in-radius is optimal as there are no patches with color 9 before this.

What would be the best way to guarantee that the patches turn to white but they stay apart. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to turn some patches grey, but in a configuration such that there are no adjacent grey patches. If that's the case, one way to do this is to use a `while` loop to search for potential patches to change color until your number of desired grey patches is reached- this will ensure that there are no adjacent grey patches since each time the while loop runs, only a patch that is 'allowed' to changed color will do so. For example:

```
to setup
  resize-world 0 10 0 10
  set-patch-size 30
  ca
  ; Until the condition is met, ask one patch to turn grey
  while [ count ( patches with [ pcolor = 9 ] ) < 20 ] [
    ; Ask one of the patches that does NOT have any grey neighbors
    ask one-of patches with [ not any? neighbors with [ pcolor = 9 ] ] [
      set pcolor 9
    ] 
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Should look something like:

[image]

Do be careful with `while` loops- if the condition is never met to 'break' or complete the loop, the loop will run indefinitely.